# Get rid of a checked exception when using NIO2 API

Tags: java, java-7, nio2, checked-exceptions

Currently, I was loading a property file from the classpath using the following code with the help of Guava API:

```
final URL fileURL = Resources.getResource("res.properties");
final File file = new File(fileURL.getFile());
```

I decided to give a try the new NIO2 API introduced in Java7SE and remove any Guava API calls so I transformed the code to the following:

```
final URL fileURL = getClass().getResource("/res.properties");
final Path path = Paths.get(fileURL.toURI());
```

But the modified code throws a checked exception in the line where conversion occurs between `URL` and `URI`. Is there any way I can get rid of it. Can I get a `Path` instance with given `URL`, for example?

P.S. I am aware that the modified code is not semantically the same as the original one - Guava's `getResource` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if resources is not found, the Java's `getResource` returns `null` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
final File file = new File(fileURL.getFile());
final Path path = file.toPath(); //can throw an unchecked exception
```

Comment: That is an option but the code becomes a bit unreadable (or let say confusing). I would like to use only the new API (without going through the old one).

Comment: BTW, this raises a few questions - why most of the getResource() methods return URLs, and on the other hand factory methods for creating Path requires URI as the constructor of File does the same?

Comment: I've tried that - doesn't work. It throws InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4. It seems the : symbol is not allowed in the String argument of Paths.get(String). It is also the documentation is not enough specific about how the argument should look like.

Comment: Nope. It throws the same exception (but with different index of the illegal character).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found:

```
final URL fileURL = getClass().getResource("/res.properties");
final URI fileURI = URI.create(fileURL.toString());
final Path path = Paths.get(fileURI);
```